# How to print a string from java to a Zebra kr203?

Tags: java, zebra-printers, epl

I am a complete newbie to kiosk printers.

I need to send a string from a java app to a zebra kr203 kiosk printer.

The machine is hooked up to a windows 7 pc and its drivers are installed. Printing test pages works fine.

I have also installed the setup utilities for the printer and they allow sending commands to it through EPL2 language. Again, I am completeley new to EPL2 but I have tried some example commands and nothing worked.

Can someone please write some basic java code to send a short string to the printer?

No GUI needed just a simple command line app.

EDIT: I found some code on google that gets the correct printService but it still won't print anything out.

EDIT NO. 2: I ended up using the Zebra SDK provided on their website. They keep code examples there which you can easily find by googling. I edited out the old code since it is useless.

Using the SDK and examples I figured out that the printer actually uses ZPL2 instead of EPL as I originally thought.

The SDK has its own API for sending commands at it works quite smoothly for me.

Comment: Hi, How could you print a ticket with zebra kr203 using java, could you share your code with me?

Comment: Hi, I´m using printer zebra KR203 using this manual https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/manuals/en-us/printer/kr203-pm-en.pdf but the sintaxis is deferent .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I ended up using:

```
String defaultPrinter = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService().getName();
com.zebra.sdk.comm.Connection myconnection = new com.zebra.sdk.comm.DriverPrinterConnection(defaultPrinter,1000,1000);
myconnection.open();
com.zebra.sdk.printer.ZebraPrinter myprinter = ZebraPrinterFactory.getInstance(myconnection);
String command = "^XA\n" +
                    "^FO50,50\n" +
                    "^A@N,20,20,E:TT0003M_.FNT\n" +
                    "^FDUplatili ste XXXX na račun XXXXXXXXXX^FS\n" +
                    "^FO50,150\n" +
                    "^A0,32,25\n" +
                    "^FD"+ date.toString()+ "^FS\n" +
                    "^FO50,250\n" +
                    "^A0,32,25^FDSlavnoska Avenija 19, 10000 Zagreb^FS\n" +
                    "^XZ";
myprinter.sendCommand(command);
myconnection.close();
```

Comment: I have copy and paste your code but I get this error "Error en la con com.zebra.sdk.comm.UsbNativeCodeConnectionException: The native code dll is not loaded." Could you please help me??

Answer (score 0):

Do you have multiple printers to choose from...or just one printer?

```
    private void printLabel() {
        try{
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("\\Your Printer Here");
            PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(fos);

            //try with the EPL commands or take a look at the ZPL programming guide
            String commands = "N\n" +
                    "A50,50,0,2,2,2,N,\"" + label + "\"\n" +
                    "B50,100,0,1,2,2,170,B,\"" + label + "\"\n" +
                    "A50,310,0,3,1,1,N,\"" + czas + "\"\n" +
                    "P1\n";

            ps.println(commands);
            ps.print("\f");
            ps.flush();
            ps.close();

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

}
`

Comment: I have multiple printers with the Zebra set to default. Also, System.out.println("Default printer: " + defaultPrinter); returns Zebra.

Comment: @user3779674 Just curious - I wrote a program that used ZPL but I only needed to use one printer so I harded-coded the path in FileOutputStream, Would post that if you like but it is probably of no use to you. I also could've helped a little with ZPL..not so much with EPL(sorry)

Comment: @born2bmild The printer should support ZPL. Please post your code and I will give it a try. I can remove all the other printers to give it a go. It's just an office test, nothing critical.

Comment: @user3779674  Hope it works for you. You may want to fiddle with the x,y coordinates and dpi. That's what I had to do with ZPL, when I changed printers...That's all I have until much later

Comment: @born2bmild what is czas?